# lowest() is not a member of std::numeric_limits

Tags: c++, gcc, qt-creator

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest() << std::endl;
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
../main.cpp:5: error: 'lowest' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<int>'
 cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest() << std::endl;
         ^
```

I am using QT Creator 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 15.04, the compiler is set to GCC by default (/usr/bin/g++).

Anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of GCC? And are you using `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`lowest`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest) function was introduced in the C++11 standard, so you need to enable C++11 compatibility with the `-std=c++11` flag (it's not enabled by default).